# .net To Mono -> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Private/public key mismatch

Tags: c#, mono

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Private/public key mismatch
  at Mono.Security.Cryptography.RSAManaged.ImportParameters (RSAParameters parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.ImportParameters (RSAParameters parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at BlaBlaFunc() [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Private/public key mismatch
  at Mono.Security.Cryptography.RSAManaged.ImportParameters (RSAParameters parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.ImportParameters (RSAParameters parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at BlaBlaFunc() [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Here is the Source Code:

```
    string foo = "blabla";

    System.Security.Cryptography.RSAParameters rsa_params = new System.Security.Cryptography.RSAParameters();

    rsa_params.Modulus = Enumerable.Range(0, pubkey.Length)
                         .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                         .Select(x => System.Convert.ToByte(pubkey.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                         .ToArray();
    rsa_params.Exponent = new byte[] { 1, 0, 1 };
    System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    System.Security.Cryptography.RSAParameters d = rsa.ExportParameters(false);
    rsa.ImportParameters(rsa_params);

    byte[] sp = rsa.Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(foo), false);
```

The .exe file which works fine in windows is compiled with vs2010. It was runned with mono under Ubuntu.

Run with this command:

```
  mono --runtime=v4.0.30319 xxx.exe
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the `ExportParameters` call generates a keypair, including private key, even though you specified `false` for the `includePrivateParameters` argument. (See the [source code](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Cryptography/RSAManaged.cs#L262)). The `ImportParameters` then overwrites only the public key (because you don't provide the private one) hence the mismatch. This may be a mono bug if it doesn't match documented behaviour. Check that and file a bug if applicable.

As a workaround, you can remove the `ExportParameters` or create a new instance that you import into.

Comment: Although I remove the ExportParameters, the result of rsa.Encrypt in Mono is not the same as in .Net. What else I can do?